# load hbm.xml query from database at runtime

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I had wrote query in hbm.xml file and used spring hibernate Template for select query from data base. but I want load query at run time Instead of load form hbm.xml file.
When application is running hibernate create map of query with key = "queryName" and
value = "object org.hibernate.engine.NamedSQLQueryDefinition with query string".
sample of query is

```
  <sql-query name="findPermission">
        <return alias="prm" class="Permission"/>
select {prm.*}
                from  permission prm
                where prm.id = :prmId
</sql-query>
```

I want load this part from data base to change query at run time also when update this query in data base load changed query an run it.
This question don't solved with criteria. for example if above query is incorrect want to change
correct an runtime without deploy war or jar file.

```
  <sql-query name="findPermission">
        <return alias="prm" class="Permission"/>
select {prm.*}
                from  tb_permission prm
                where prm.id = :prmId
</sql-query>
```

In this sample permission change to tb_permission.
I try to change Hibernate sessionFactory object and create own sessionFactory
but other created in this object similar alise and classMetaDate , ...
must be change to load and run query.
How can i do it??

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rebuild the session factory every time you want to do a change, but I would suggest you to instead inline the query directly into your code like this:

```
session.createSQLQuery("select {prm.*} from permission prm where prm.id = :prmId")
    .addReturn(Permission.class, "prm");
```

When you run your application in the debug mode, you can change code and the HotSwap technology of the JVM will replace the method body properly to include the new code. This way, you don't have to restart your application all the time.